# Advertisements are combined?

Tags: android, admob, adsense, adview

I have admob integrated into two of my published applications on the play store. On AdMob however, all of my revenue, page views, etc. is combined into just one app. All my app statistics are showing up into one of my combined apps. How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't see how this question is related to programming.

Comment: @sweeper why would you think so?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have not used the same ad unit ids in both apps. Generate separate ad units for each app on the admob site and use the individual app's ad unit ids in the respective apps.

Another possibility (if you have used the right ad units in each app) is that only one of your app is actually being used. The other one might be dormant. Just a possibility. But more chances are that of you having used the same ad unit ids in both apps.

Comment: So is it okay to update my app and change the app unit id. There will be no problems when uploading the new apk with improved app unit id's, right?

Comment: yes, its just another update. They are your ad units you can change them anytime. nothing wrong in that.